# How do I report an error in the USB install package?

Tags: server, 18.04, usb-installation

I have encountered an issue with the current live installer for Ubuntu 18.04.1 server.

Whenever I run an integrity check on the drive there is always 3 errors. I have tried multiple drives and writing them multiple times. I have also verified the iso.

Now where do I report this?

Is there a package that is concerned with making the iso image where I can report this?

Something must have gone wrong in build the ISO, since the ISO it self passes the checksum, but the files packed in it does not.

Also: Can someone please confirm or refute this issue?

<strike>Also, it doesn't show me which files has errors, and pressing any key after the check will reboot.</strike>
**Update**: I found out which files fail.

Comment: Not really @karel. I have reviewed that page, but found nothing concerning the creation of the installer ISO.

Comment: @beruic that what karel posted is a generic guideline on how to report bugs.

Comment: @Rinzwind i am aware of that, and I have reported bugs before. This however is a bug specific to the Ubuntu installer integrity check, and I cannot find a package to report that on.

Comment: The installer is "ubiquity" so I would assume anything related to that needs would be against that package. So https://packages.ubuntu.com/cosmic/ubiquity By the way: the integrity check(?) That might not be an Ubuntu package.  You can check a live dvd from windows using a checksums program.

Comment: @rinzwind Is it possible to remove the duplicate mark from this question? The package referred to in the answer by slangasek is not mentioned in https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This integrity check fails because the 18.04.1 live server image was reissued as 18.04.1.0 with a spot fix for a bug that caused the configured apt sources.list to be wrong on the system post-installation.  The nature of the spot fix meant that the image was built by modifying the previous 18.04.1 image rather than pushing a completely new image through the usual build chain, and as a result the need to update md5sum.txt within the image was overlooked.

You can do an offline verification that the image has not been compromised by checking both the gpg-signed checksums at http://releases.ubuntu.com/18.04.1/SHA256SUMS.gpg + http://releases.ubuntu.com/18.04.1/SHA256SUMS or by verifying that ./casper/filesystem.squashfs.gpg - which is listed among the modified files - is a  matching signature for ./casper/filesystem.squashfs and issued by the correct key (which is to say, the same key used for other images released by Ubuntu).

We will not reissue the image to correct the wrong checksum.  Instead, this image will be superseded by the 18.04.2 point release early next year.

As for the question of where to report this issue, the correct project to report image bugs is https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-cdimage/